# how to add multiple different types of product to cart

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a shopping cart where I am trying to add different types of product e.g. `Mobiles`, `clothes` etc.
I have created a `add_to_cart` method and added products to session, then at last I save all products to database table.
But now I am confused how to add different product because parameter for different products are different e.g.

```
1. product_id, quantity, price for mobile.
2. product_id, quantity, price, size for cloths.
....
```

should I create different `add_to_cart()` method for different types of products.

Answer (score 0):

In your scenario it would be better to have the product options sent as a JSON string and then decode it on the server side so that you don't have to worry about the different options for each product.

So product one might have options like:

```
{color: "black", size: "large"}
```

And product two might have:

```
{memory: "2 GB", harddisk: "750 GB"}
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

As long as products have at least some common fields, writing different methods is not entirely justified.

The other attributes can simply be passed as key-value pairs.

When writing the data into a database, you could apply [EAV modeling](http://www.iwilldomybest.com/2008/08/php-mysql-tip-3/).

Comment: thanks jack i got it a little bit, can you be more practical in my case, if you don't mind.

Comment: @user_quest the common attributes are passed as regular function parameters, the rest is passed as an array with field names as the keys. As for EAV you should be able to just follow the example link

Answer (score 0):

you can keep using the **add_to_cart()**

instead, you'll add an array parameter, say, "attributes" or "extra" and
add there *specific/unique* product valued keys.

then in database you create an "attributes" column of variable size eg. VARCHAR(128)
and add those attributes encoded as **JSONs**

you can still search for any product then using "LIKE '%"attribute" :%'" (json)

this doesnt forcing you to create additional columns for every new product attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep basic common things in primary array and specification in specification array as follows
Products[mobile] =>array(name => 'test1', price =>'20' specification=array('color'=>red,model=>'N70' etc....))

Products[cloths] =>array(name => 'test1', price =>'30' specification=array('size'=>'XL',color=>'yello',etc......))

Comment: Thanks Ganesh, but how to manage database table for this. should i store specification in one field in cart table.